# whats the best way to pass a full date time into a URL in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, routes

i have a full datetime object that i need to pass in as a parameter in a URL.

what is the best way to do this so it fully can get converted to a csharp DateTime object and not lose any precision ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass it as a `Ticks`. and convert the `Ticks` back to DateTime. `Ticks` is a long datatype and datetime accepts `long` datatype to be converted to `DateTime`

For example, in mvc, your url looks like this `myweb.com/Pass/Date/634164331846947633` you can get the 3rd segment of your url which is by default `id` and convert it to `DateTime`.